# customizeText devextreme not working

Tags: jquery, devexpress, devextreme

```js
datagrid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
  columns: [{
    dataField: "STCG",
    caption: "STCG",
    format: 'fixedPoint',
    allowFiltering: false,
    precision: 2,
    customizeText: function(cellElement, cellInfo) {
      var fieldData = cellInfo.value;

      if (fieldData >= 0) {
        cellInfo.cellElement.addClass("greencolortext");
      } else {
        cellInfo.cellElement.addClass("redcolortext");
      }
    }
  }]
}).dxDataGrid("instance");
```

```css
.greencolortext {
  color: #2DC48D;
}

.redcolortext {
  color: #bf4e6a;
}
```

i am trying to change the font color of data in cell 
if data in greater than or equal to zero text will be green else red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [customizeText](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#customizeText) method doesn't take 2 arguments. Well if you open browser console you will see javascript errors.

In your case you can use the [cellTemplate](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#cellTemplate) option:

```
cellTemplate: function($cell, cellInfo) {
    var fieldData = cellInfo.data.STCG;
    if (fieldData >= 0) {
        $cell.addClass("greencolortext");
    } else {
        $cell.addClass("redcolortext");
    }

    $cell.append(cellInfo.text);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xL32can9/).

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - [dxDataGrid - customizeText does not change cell text under certain conditions](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T237710)

> The customizeText callback function is intended for changing the cell
>   text. If you wish to completely customize your cell content, use only
>   [cellTemplate](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/?version=14_2#cellTemplate).

Hope this help..